# Find the velocity of the falling object when it touches the water

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, kinematics

The question:

An object falls from a hovering surf-lifesaving helicopter over a port at
$500$ m above sea level. Find the velocity of the object when it hits the water when
the acceleration of the object is $0.2v^2 − g$. (Note that $g \not= 9.8$, because they did not state anywhere.)

Since they gave us $a$ in terms of $v$, and a value for $x$, I used:

- $v\frac{dv}{dx} = 0.2v^2-g$
- $\frac{dv}{dx} = 0.2v - gv^{-1}$
- $\int\frac{1}{0.2v - gv^{-1}} dv=\int dx$
- $\frac{5}{2}\ln(\frac{1}{5}v^2-g)+c=x$

How do I find the value of $c$, given only one info and where do I go next, after that?

Comment: Your analysis looks OK except that you should watch the sign of $1/5 v^2 - g$.  Then if you treat $g$ as unknown you have two unknowns and just one equation, so you need something more to solve for both.  I suspect the question intends you to assume the standard value for $g$.

Comment: $g$ could be $9.8$, but usually, the question would tell us, won't it? I do not want to make the mistake of falsely assuming

Comment: You need to assume something more to find $c$ if nothing else is given.  Alternatively, you need to express $c$ and your final answer with $g$ remaining a variable throughout.

Comment: This question may get complicated as the direction of accn. may change in midair.

Comment: You may also ask this in  PhySE

Comment: @Ramanujam:  I think you find that $v$ approaches a finite (negative) limit.  In broad brush, $x$ is $500$ initially, $v=0$, and under the force of $g$, $v$ decreases (i.e. increasingly negative) and the argument of the $\log$ term approaches zero as $x$ approaches $-\infty$, while $v$ approaches a finite (negative) limit when the resistance term balances gravity.  This is the terminal velocity.  Accordingly the $1/5 v^2 - g$ term should not change sign.

Comment: At the point of dropping, velocity is 0 and position 500. Can't you use definite integral with those limits?

Answer (score 1):

First you find the path $x(t)$ along which our object moves. For this, simply solve the differential equation $\dot v=v^2-g$. You can solve this by separation of the variables using partial fraction decomposition of the integrand. Now you have a function $v(t)$, presumably with a free parameter. Since the object falls from a hovering object, its velocity at $t=0$ is $0$. So use the free parameter to enforce $v(0)=0$. You now have $v(t)$. Integrate it to obtain $x(t)$, again with a free parameter. Use this free parameter to enforce $x(0)=500\mathrm m$, since that's the height where it starts falling. Now find the point in time where $x(t)=0$ and find the corresponding velocity.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

$$
-\dot v = \mu v^2-g, \ v(0) = 0, \Rightarrow v = \sqrt{\frac{g}{\mu}}\tanh\left(\sqrt{\mu g}t\right)
$$

but

$$
\dot h = \sqrt{\frac{g}{\mu}}\tanh\left(\sqrt{\mu g}t\right),\ \  h(0) = h_0
$$

so

$$
h = h_0 + \frac{\ln\left(\cosh\left(\sqrt{\mu g}t\right)\right)}{\mu}
$$

and $h=0$ for $t = \frac{\cosh^{-1}\left(e^{h_0\mu}\right)}{\sqrt{\mu g}}$

hence

$$
v = \sqrt{\frac{g}{\mu}}\left(1+e^{-h_0\mu}\right)\sqrt{\tanh\left(\frac{h_0\mu}{2}\right)}
$$

and after substitution of $h_0=500, g = 9.8, \mu = 0.2$ in due units, we obtain

$$
v = 7[m/s]
$$

Comment: $h_0=\frac12 gt^2$ only applies to free fall without air resistance. This is with air resistance, though. It's where the $v^2$ comes from.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos you have got a point, but he still got the right answer. Idk how.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that $500$ is a large distance for the object to reach an eventual velocity that renders the effective acceleration zero, i.e. $0.2v^2 - g =0$, which leads to

$$v= \sqrt{\frac g{0.2}}=\sqrt{5g}=7\text{m/s}$$